# How to color text inside of a \def

Tags: macros, color, environments

I am trying to color some text inside an xdef command. I am getting the following error: Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.
Does anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks!

edit: Modified example to be a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\def\var{}
\newenvironment{environment}[1]
{
    \foreach \i/\j in {#1}
    {
        \xdef\var{\var \color{dkgreen}\i\color{black} \j}
    }
    \var
    \linebreak
}

\begin{environment}{a/b, c/d}
\end{environment}       
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Just to make sure, have you defined `dkblue` in your document?  If that's not the issue, then you'll need to post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: it is never safe to use `\xdef` on general latex tokens. Also you are missing `%` from almost every line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to protect `\textcolor` from expanding, and avoid adding spurious spaces:

```
\def\japivar{}
\newenvironment{myenvironment}[3]
{%
    {\let\textcolor\relax
      \xdef\japivar{#1 #2(}%
    \foreach \i/\j/\k in {#3}%
    {%
        \xdef\japivar{\japivar \textcolor{dkblue}{\i} \j}%
    }}%
}
{}
```

This is assuming that the tokens you pass in as `#1,#2,#3` are safe in an `\xdef`.